# How to write a function using natural order and comparators

Tags: java, code-reuse

I am new to Java, and I am trying to implement a sort algorithm which may use the natural order or a given comparator argument.

Say I have a comparable class `C` with some natural order `compareTo`, a Comparator subclass `ByAltOrder`, And I have a `Comparator<C>` method which returns a new `ByAltOrder`.

```
public class C implements Comparable<C> {
        ...                                     //fields and constructor
    public int compareTo(C that) { ... }        //natural order
    public Comparator<C> altOrder() {           //some alternative order
        return new ByAltOrder();
    }
    public class ByAltOrder implements Comparator<C>{
        public int compare(C x, C y) { ... }
    }
}
```

I want to write a function which may use the natural order or the alternative order. I know how to write a function that uses *either* the natural order or the alternative order, but I do not want to write the same code twice with minor differences. Is that possible?

Say I want to write a function returning maximum of a non-empty Array. With natural order it looks like this:

```
public C max(C[] xs){
    res = xs[0];
    for (i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {
        if (xs[i].compareTo(res) > 0) {
            res = points[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

And with Comparator it looks like this and I can pass `x.altOrder()` as the second argument:

```
public C max(C[] xs, Comparator c){
    res = xs[0];
    for (i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {
        if (c.compare(xs[i], res) > 0) {
            res = points[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

But how I do write a function that incorporates both?

Edit: I got that there is an `Arrays.sort` in Java, but implementing sort or max is just a toy example for my question about passing Comparators / code reuse / java practice. Perhaps I didn't make it clear about this.

Comment: Your first method should simply delegate to the second one and pass Comparator.naturalOrder() as second argument. Please, don't use raw types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically JB Nizet is right.
This is enough :

```
public C max(C[] xs){
    return max(xs, Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

public C max(C[] xs, Comparator<? super C> c){
    C res = xs[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {
        if (c.compare(xs[i], res) > 0) {
            res = points[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now, concretely, writing these processings seem not relevant 
To find the max element (in terms of `Comparable/Comparator`) of an array, you could just use `Arrays.stream().max` :

```
C max = Arrays.stream(xs).max(c);
```

or

```
C max =  Arrays.stream(xs).max(new ByAltOrder());
```

By handling the `null` case if the array is empty (thanks dear Holger), your  methods could be as simple as :

```
public C findMax(C[] xs){
   return findMax(xs, Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

public C findMax(C[] xs, Comparator<? super C> c){
    return Arrays.stream(xs).max(c).orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you truly want to avoid code duplication, you should not implement that operation at all.

```
Comparator<C> altOrder = …;
C[] array = …;
C naturalMax = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array));// natural order
C altMax     = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array), altOrder); // alternative order
```

Note that `Arrays.asList` does not copy but only wraps the array, so there is no performance consideration preventing to use these methods.

By the way, `ByAltOrder` and `altOrder()` should both be `static`, as they don’t depend on a specific instance of `C`.

If you want to implement these methods as an exercise, other answers already pointed to it, use delegation and `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

If you are not using Java 8 or newer, this builtin comparator is not available, but you could work-around it using `Collections.reverseOrder(Collections.reverseOrder())` to get a comparator with the same behavior, but, of course, you should replace that with `Comparator.naturalOrder()` as soon as you migrate to Java 8 or newer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one comment:

"By the way, ByAltOrder and altOrder() should both be static, as they don’t depend on a specific instance of C."
This depends on `altOrder`. For example, if `altOrder(x, y)` compares the distance from `x` to `this` and from `y` to `this`, then it depends on the specific instance of C.

Comment: @Y.Pei indeed, there might be use cases that incorporate state from a specific `C` instance. It wasn’t clear from the question whether you have such a use case. But even then, I’d keep only `altOrder()` as instance method and still implement `ByAltOrder` as `static` (or top level) class, but let it receive the necessary values in the constructor. That way, it only keeps the necessary values instead of a reference to another `C` instance. Further, it ensures consistent behavior regardless of whether the `C` instance is modified later-on.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public <C extends Comparable<? super C>> C max(C[] xs){
    return max(xs, Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

public <C> C max(C[] xs, Comparator<C> c){
    C res = xs[0];
    for (C x: xs) {
        if (c.compare(x, res) > 0) {
            res = x;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```